# Apply Particles to Rigged model with weights

Tags: rigging, particles, weight-painting

I have a rigged model that I applied a particle system to. With the particle system on, the particles move with the rig like I want them to, but when I convert the particles to the model and join them they no longer have correct weights. I need to export this to unity and I have to apply the particles to do that. Is there a way to keep the weights one the particles after I have converted them to a mesh or do I have to painstakingly paint each one to the correct bone?

[image]

this is my model

[image]

This is how it bends with the particle system active. Great!

[image]

Now when I convert the particles to a mesh and join them, this is how they move. Is there a way to convert it to a mesh and join it to the rigged model but keep the weights the particles had? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particle instances have no weights. They are just placed on the mesh that is deformed by the *Armature* modifier. (Modifiers must be in the correct order: *Armature* first, then *Particle System*.)

If you want to export the rigged model with particles then **you need to add weights to the converted particles. One easy way is to transfer the weights from the body mesh after you have converted the particles.** This requires a few steps:

- set the armature to *Rest Position*
- convert the particle to mesh objects by pressing the button "*Make Instances Real*" (in older Blender versions it's called "*Convert to Mesh*"). The button is located in the settings of the *Particle System* modifier.
- move all created particle instance objects to a new collection (<kbd>M</kbd>)
- make them *Single User* objects. Keep them select and choose viewport menu *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data*. This step is needed to be able to join them into one object.
- click one particle object to make it the *active* object (=highlighted in *orange*, the others highlighted in *red*) and join them to a single object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)
- select the *particle* object and then the *body* object (=*active* object, highlighted *orange*) and transfer the weights with menu entry *Object > Link/Transfer Data > Transfer Mesh Data* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

  - in the first *Transfer Mesh Data* popup select `Vertex Groups`
  - in the next *Transfer Mesh Data* popup select *Source Layers Selection*  = `All Layers` and *Destination Layers Mapping* = `By Name`. The popup is the *Adjust Last Operation* popup at the bottom left of the screen (<kbd>F9</kbd> if you missed it)
- the weights should be transferred now. Turn off the *Particle System* modifier on the *body* mesh. Then join the *particle* mesh with the *body* mesh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)
- that's it. Set the armature to *Pose Position* to test it

Comment: Thank you that worked splendidly. I appreciate the help and the detailed step by step instructions. hope you have a good day :)